# Where to store and get bearer token with Symfony & react?

Tags: reactjs, api, symfony, bearer-token

I'm developing a react app for frontend and a symfony api for backend. I would like users access datas thanks to an api. I installed Lexik JWT Authentication successly.

I read that Bearer Tokens should not be sent to the response and should not be stored neither in local storage nor in a client cookie file, for security reasons (XSS). So I overrided the listener to this:

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('BEARER', $tokenJWT, (
            new \DateTime())
            ->add(new \DateInterval('PT' . $this->jwtTokenTTL . 'S')), '/', null, $this->cookieSecure));
```

Now, I would like that my react frontend has access to this token in order to send it in requests. How to do this? Is there a better method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I read that Bearer Tokens should not be sent to the response and
> should not be stored neither in local storage nor in a client cookie
> file, for security reasons (XSS). So I overrided the listener to this:

This is not true as most of the real world applications use this method. Unless some drastic method comes along you can proceed with storing in either localstorage or cookie.

You might have read that *You should not send JWT with sensitive data to the frontend*. If you are using JWT containing sensible data make sure that you verify it and encrypt and send it to the client side.

If you are unsure what info your JWT contains you can visit https://jwt.io/ and see what it contains. Make sure to encrypt your JWT and decode on client side if you can. But if it's already encrypted you can leave it